# “en distanciel” vs “à distance”

Tags: synonymes, phrase

How can one decide when to use “en distanciel” or “à distance”? Or are they always interchangeable?

Examples:

https://www.20minutes.fr/politique/3004323-20210322-coronavirus-elisabeth-borne-hospitalisee-etat-sante-voie-amelioration:

> La ministre a été testée positive au coronavirus la semaine dernière, et assurait pouvoir continuer à exercer ses fonctions **en distanciel**.

https://www.pennmedicine.org/fr-fr/global-medicine/support-services/second-opinions:

> Seconde opinion **à distance** pour les patients internationaux.

Comment: Maybe a local (France métropolitaine) opinion but I've only started hearing 'en distanciel' during the first lockdown. Although quite common in many countries, WFH only really started getting traction with COVID in France, so the related vocabulary is still in its infancy and it may take some time for one of these 2 wordings to become more natural (if that ever happens...).

Comment: @vc74 same, first time I read en distanciel.

Comment: Des trucs tellement récents que j'ai noté que le GDT trouve même acceptable la graphie avec un [t](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26558303), et celle avec un [c](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353423) pour _présentiel_.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, les deux formes sont utilisées aujourd'hui de façon souvent interchangeables.

Une des raisons du succès de **distanciel** est certainement sa symétrie avec **présentiel**, plus courant et attesté depuis longtemps, et la flexibilité de ces deux mots qui peuvent être adjectifs comme substantifs.

[image]

On peut aussi trouver une légère nuance de sens entre « **enseignement à distance** » qui décrit plutôt un enseignement conçu pour être apporté à distance par des enseignants parfois dédiés (on parlait de « **télé-enseignement** » ou de « **cours par correspondance** » avant Internet) et l'alternative « **enseignement distanciel** », « **enseignement présentiel** » imposée par des circonstances extra-scolaires aux élèves et enseignants depuis le printemps 2020.

Comment: Great point! I was wondering why anyone would come up with a synonym for “à distance”. Might also explain the alternative spelling "distantiel".

Answer (score 3):

Les deux formulations sont synonymes. La seule différence est que « en distanciel » est un néologisme apparu récemment.

[L' Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/presentiel-distanciel) préconise l'usage de « à distance. »